# Centering EditText views in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

[image]

If you notice the EditText views for Email and Password, the line isn't centered. In the design and preview modes in Android Studio, they looked centered, but when I ran it on my phone this is what showed. I'm having trouble making it centered. Here's my code of what it currently is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:id="@+id/emailTextLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordTextLabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailTextLabel"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordTextLabel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordTextLabel"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/keep_me_signed_in"
        android:id="@+id/keepMeSignedInCheckBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordEditText"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/keepMeSignedInCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/use_without_account"
        android:id="@+id/use_without_account_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `EditText` width to `match_parent` and give `margin` from left and right, and remove `android:layout_alignLeft` , `android:layout_alignStart`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTextLabel"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I don't know why I didn't think of doing this haha.

Comment: centering view with margins is very very VERY bad practice.

Comment: @P.Ilyin yes i know that, but i have given answer according to OP's question.

Comment: @P.Ilyin so what would be a better practice? I'm new to android programming and want to know the better way.

Comment: better to use special properties of XML elements. Most of views have android:layout_centerHorizontal property for centering in relativeLayout. See my answer below this answer

Comment: margins works fine only if view have match_parent value of layout_width. android:layout_centerHorizontal is a universal property, that works fine ALWAYS. Using universal solutions better than other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" is best solution for centering views

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="Тема"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, I tried it out and it works. Not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: @RRR he will use other good solution: creating dimentions resources for different display sizes

Comment: @RRR I did think about that, which is why I am using your solution :]